# Script editor does not open in Spark AR Studio

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I have installed Spark AR Studio on Windows. I was able to work with basic effects. However when I tried to create a Script asset and open it up, it keeps failing with the error code 800A03EA. Source is shown as Microsoft JScript compilation error. I can see the file using Notepad and it only has two line in there.

```
// How to load in modules
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const Scene = require('Scene');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SparkAR Studio tries opening your scripts with the *default editor assigned to .js files on your operating system*.

Assign Visual Studio Code / Sublime / etc. to be your standard way of opening .js files on Windows and SparkAR will open it when you click on it

Answer (score 1):

To set default editor for Js files you can just create empty js file - right click on it - choose default program to open and go to your favourite editor (sublime, vscode, etc). That's all

Answer (score 0):

Set Atom/VS code/Sublime as your default JS editor.

Comment: I could not find an option in Spark AR Studio where I could change the default JS Editor. It will be helpful if you could point me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `script.js` file and a menu window will open. Click on 'Reveal in Explorer' and it will take you to the location. There, right click on the `script.js` file and open it with any other editor (e.g. Atom).